# C# make a constant array, then use it

Tags: c#, constants

I'm quite new to C#. I have found several workarounds for my goal, but I'm asking the best way to do it, using the native functions of the framework.

Let's say I have to develop a communication protocol. I need to store a constant (ready-only) array for the desired functions. I.e.:

```
public static readonly IReadOnlyList<byte> CMD1 = new byte[] { 0x03, 0x55 };
```

Later, I would define a `SendCommand` function that needs to take the correct command, complete it with parameters and checksum. Something like this:

```
List<byte> msg = Commands.CMD1.ToList(); // <-- DOESN'T WORK
msg.Add(some_parameter);
msg.Add(checksum(msg));
serialPort.Write(msg.ToArray(), 0, msg.Count);
```

Here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/hh192385(v=vs.110).aspx

it seems the `ToList()` method is available for the `IReadOnlyList` interface, but the compiler doesn't accept it.

Two questions:

1. why I cannot use the `ToList()` method here?
2. is there a better approach?

Comment: "Doesn't work" doesn't tell us anything about the problem here. Tell us why you think it doesn't work. Does the compiler complain? If so then tell us what it says. Does it crash at runtime? If so then tell us about the exception. Please note that calling `.ToList()` on that specific field works just fine (I just tested it) which makes it all the more important for you to tell us why you think this doesn't work. Since the specific `ToList()` being used is an extension method declared in `System.Linq.Enumerable` I suspect that you're just missing `using System.Linq;` in your .cs file.

Comment: It would help if you include the error message.

Comment: `List<byte> msg = Commands.CMD1.ToList();` should work, so tell us the exact problem is giving to you

Comment: I suppose you need `using Sytem.Linq` on top of your source-code file

Comment: A "constant" array... first time I hear that. Did you mean a **read-only** array in the title?

Comment: `List<byte> msg = new List<int>(Commands.CMD1);` if you don't want Linq

Comment: I said `read-only` in the text. If you want I can change the title also! I explained below what "doesn't work" mean: the IDE doesn't find the method at all. I've already have `using Systme.Linq` and I said I'm quite new to C#....

Comment: @Mark doesn't VS give you a light-bulb with options besides the error message?

Comment: I guess Visual Studio puts a red mark under it. If you put the mouse over it,does it give you any explanation?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto You´re referring to ReSharper which does this.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I have never used ReSharper and I got this option in Visual Studio. Even the Community edition supports it

Comment: As said, it complains about the lack of that method. The error message is in Italian but it should sound like this "IReadOnlyList<byte>" doesn't contain a definition of 'ToList". Perhaps you miss an 'using' directive". But at the top of the file I actually have `using System.Linq`.

Comment: Hmm..that's exactly the error you would get without `using System.Linq`.
Maybe you miss a reference...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code seems to be off very much. You are converting a read-only list to a new list, then back to an array.

Why not use arrays from the start and rely on the underlying interfaces for the rest? You might want to use `IEnumerable<byte>` for example for your checksum method, or use byte array from the start.

```
public static readonly byte[] CMD1 = new byte[] { 0x03, 0x55 };

List<byte> msg = new List<byte>(CMD1);
msg.Add(some_parameter);
msg.Add(checksum(msg));
serialPort.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);
```

Comment: I think you don't need `new byte[]` as per c# 5/6

Comment: How should I define `msg` and assing `CMD1` to the first bytes?

Comment: @Mark you can use `List<byte> msg = new List<byte>(CMD1);`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put you commands in an enumeration, so you can select them by name. You won't have to remember them all.

```
public enum CommandsEnum
{
    Com1 = 0x03,
    Com2 = 0x05
}
```

Then you can easily add them in collections and use them everywhere

```
var cmds = new List<byte>();

cmds.Add((byte)CommandsEnum.Com1);
cmds.Add((byte)CommandsEnum.Com1);

serialPort.Write(cmds.ToArray(), 0, cmds.Count);
```